# Programatically select columns from a dataframe with udf

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark.
I am trying to extract columns of a dataframe using a config file which contains a UDF. 
If I define the select column as a list on the client it works but if I import the list from a config file the column list is of the type string.
Is there an alternate way.

opening spark-shell using pyspark .

```
*******************************************************************
version 2.2.0
Using Python version 2.7.16 (default, Mar 18 2019 18:38:44)
SparkSession available as 'spark'

*******************************************************************


jsonDF = spark.read.json("/tmp/people.json")
jsonDF.show()

+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+

jsonDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)


jsonCurDF = jsonDF.filter(jsonDF.age.isNotNull()).cache()

# Define the UDF

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
@udf("long")
def squared_udf(s):
  return s * s


# Selecting the columns from a list.

colSelList = ['age', 'name', squared_udf('age')]
jsonCurDF.select(colSelList).show()

+---+------+----------------+
|age|  name|squared_udf(age)|
+---+------+----------------+
| 30|  Andy|             900|
| 19|Justin|             361|
+---+------+----------------+

# If I use an external config file 

colSelListStr = ["age", "name" , "squared_udf('age')"]
jsonCurDF.select(colSelListStr).show()
```

The above command fails "cannot resolve '`squared_udf('age')'

Tried registering the function, tried selectExpr and using the column function.

In the colSelList the udf call is translated to a column type.

```
print colSelList[2]
Column<squared_udf(age)

print colSelListStr[2]
squared_udf('age')

print column(colSelListStr[2])
Column<squared_udf('age')
```

What am I doing wrong here? or is there an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's because squared_age is considered as string not a function when you are passing it from a list.
There is a round way you can do this and you don't need to import UDF for this.
Assume this is the list you need to select

[image]

directly passing this list will result into an error because squared_age doesn't contain in this data frame

[image]

so first you take all the columns of existing df into a list by

```
existing_cols = df.columns
```

[image]

and your these are the columns you need
[image]

now take intersection of both the lists
it will you give you a common element list

```
intersection = list(set(existing_cols) & set(col_list))
```

now try like this

```
newDF= df.select(intersection).rdd.map(lambda x: (x["age"], x["name"], x["age"]*x["age"])).toDF(col_list)
```

which will give you this

[image]

hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. Squared function is just an example. Writing the lambda function will not be generic in my case. My final goal is to have a list of udf's and extract the data from the dataframe based on a config file.